# Framer Motion causing styling delay

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, sass, framer-motion

I recently added Framer Motion to my next.js project for some fade in / out animation on page loads and navigation to make things look a bit smoother. In dev mode, everything works perfectly (figures), but in production when someone navigates to a new page, the fade in works, but none of my styling is applied for a split second and all you see is the raw HTML until the animation finishes. Any ideas as to why this is happening? Below is my Transition code and my _app.js structure. I appreciate any help and insight!

```
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import styles from '@/styles/components/Transition.module.scss'

const Transition = ({ children }) => {

    const { asPath } = useRouter();

    const variants = {
        out: {
            opacity: 0,
            y: 0,
            transition: {
                duration: 0.2
            }
        },
        in: {
            opacity: 1,
            y: 0,
            transition: {
                duration: 0.4
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={styles.example_1}>
            <AnimatePresence
                initial={false}
                mode='wait'
            >
                <motion.div
                    key={asPath}
                    variants={variants}
                    animate="in"
                    initial="out"
                    exit="out"
                >
                    {children}
                </motion.div>
            </AnimatePresence>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Transition;
```

_app.js

```
return (
    <Transition>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <DatabaseContextProvider>
          <StorageContextProvider>
            <React.Suspense fallback={<BasicLoader />}>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </React.Suspense>
          </StorageContextProvider>
        </DatabaseContextProvider>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </Transition>
  );
```